# Google Places autocomplete API not returning postal codes

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-api

I have been googling this for hours and I have not found a solution.  When I call:

> "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input="+WebUtility.UrlEncode(MYADDRESSSPEC)+"&key="+MYAPIKEY;

I get things like:

```
123 Main St, Somewhere, Ohio United States
123 Main St, Somewhere Else, Indiana, United States
```

I've looked at the optional arguments and I cannot find one for ZIP/postal code.  I noticed the textsearch API does return ZIP codes.  I could run it through autocomplete as someone is typing the address and THEN run each result through the textsearch API but I want to accomplish this in just ONE web service call.  Does anyone know how?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think the autocomplete API supports returning postcodes in the predictions array. Your best bet (albeit cumbersome) is to do do the autocomplete query and  run a `details` query each of the `place_id` entries returned.

Comment: Thank you!! That did it!  Before reading this, I had tried making multiple calls to textsearch per address and it was MUCH slowere.  Details is quick!

Comment: Glad to be of help. I reposted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the autocomplete API supports returning postcodes in the predictions array. Your best bet (albeit cumbersome) is to do the autocomplete query and run a [details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) query for each of the `place_id` entries returned.

Comment: I think you're correct.  I mean, why charge for one query when they can charge you for 2?

Comment: @MattMcCallum Best thing I've ever read on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `type=(regions)` filter to the url (as query param) and then you can search on postal codes. It is not completely fine because it still can't find all the postal codes I think. But this might be what you need.